# Unable to check empty validation inside the filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have tried empty validation using ternary operator, but it's not returning data.
Below is my json object

> var data = [   {
>       "name": "test",
>       "domain": "domain1",
>       "subdomain": "subdomain1",
>       "type": "yes"   }, {      "name": "hello",        "domain": "domain2",        "subdomain": "subdomain6",      "type": "no"    },
>       {         "name": "test1",        "domain": "domain2",        "subdomain": "subdomain6",      "type": "no",
>           "desc":"helloo"   }
>        ];

Below is my filter js code

```js
 var data = [{
  "name": "test",
  "domain": "domain1",
  "subdomain": "subdomain1",
  "type": "yes"
 },
    {
  "name": "hello",
  "domain": "domain2",
  "subdomain": "subdomain6",
  "type": "no"
 },
    {
  "name": "test1",
  "domain": "domain2",
  "subdomain": "subdomain6",
  "type": "no",
        "desc":"helloo"
 }
    
];

var namesearch = ["hello"];
var result = data.filter((d)=>{return 
namesearch.length > 0 ? namesearch.includes(d.name):''  });
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a small mistake in your code. You cannot use line break after the return keyword, `javascript` will return undefined in this case.

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "test",
    domain: "domain1",
    subdomain: "subdomain1",
    type: "yes"
  },
  {
    name: "hello",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no"
  },
  {
    name: "test1",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
    desc: "helloo"
  }
];

var namesearch = ["hello"];
var result = data.filter(d => {
  return namesearch.length > 0 ? namesearch.includes(d.name) : "";
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use implicit return for arrow function for this case. (Also since filter function expects boolean return value, changed it slightly. Ofcourse it will still convert from '' to false)

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "test",
    domain: "domain1",
    subdomain: "subdomain1",
    type: "yes"
  },
  {
    name: "hello",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no"
  },
  {
    name: "test1",
    domain: "domain2",
    subdomain: "subdomain6",
    type: "no",
    desc: "helloo"
  }
];

var namesearch = ["hello"];
var result = data.filter(
  ({ name }) => namesearch.length > 0 && namesearch.includes(name)
);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: I am unable to get the name having "he" and domain either  ["domain5","domain2"]; below is my code   var namesearch = ["he"];
var domain = ["domain5","domain2"];
var result = data.filter((d)=>{
return (namesearch.length > 0 ? namesearch[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(d.name.toLowerCase()) > -1:'') &&  domain.length > 0 ? domain.includes(d.domain):''
});

Comment: @ramumothukuri, way of indexOf call is wrong. Try this var result = data.filter(d => {
  return (namesearch.length > 0
    ? d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(namesearch[0].toLowerCase()) > -1
    : "") && domain.length > 0
    ? domain.includes(d.domain)
    : "";
});.  (some thing like "hello".indexOf("he"))